# Vertical line on mouseover behaving unexpectedly (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add a vertical line that hovers above my chart on mouseover, like in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136

The difference is my page involves small multiples. Here's my (semi-working) Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/H5r704WoIOBFXrPm2WFp?p=preview

The following code:

```
    var vertical = d3.select(svgHook)
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "remove")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "19")
      .style("width", "1px")
      .style("height", h)
      .style("top", "10px")
      .style("bottom", "30px")
      .style("left", "30px")
      .style("background", "#fff");

d3.select(svgHook)
    .on("mousemove", function(){  
       mousex = d3.mouse(this);
       mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
       vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
    .on("mouseover", function(){  
       mousex = d3.mouse(this);
       mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
       vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
```

Produces the following problems:

- The vertical line scrolls across everything on the page, including titles and axes, and not just the `path.area` of each chart (or that of any single chart).
- The line leaves copies of itself, which can sometimes be removed by slowly, carefully mousing over them again; sometimes not.
- The line doesn't appear underneath the cursor. It appears far to the left. I've tried fiddling with different values, and I just can't get its position right.

I'm indifferent to whether, on mouseover, the vertical line hovers above a single chart, or above all of them. I can't figure out how to achieve either.  How do I fix this? http://plnkr.co/edit/H5r704WoIOBFXrPm2WFp?p=preview

Comment: Would you mind if I add a "path" instead of a "div" for the vertical line? Cause' I believe a path (element of the same svg) would be more correctly positioned in all scenarios than a HTML element.

Comment: Sure, if you're able to demonstrate how to do that, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Yes I'll add a Plunkr soon! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fork of your code with the working vertical line: 
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/shthV6LMfldiWKaH2k1p?p=preview)

Relevant code:

```
var vertical = d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.'+selectedState)
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "remove").style({stroke:'#000', 'stroke-width': '1px', 'pointer-events': 'none'});

d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.'+selectedState).on("mousemove", function(){  
   mousex = d3.mouse(this);
   vertical.style("display", null).attr("d", function () {
   var d = "M" + mousex[0] + "," + (size.h-padding.bottom);
   d += " " + mousex[0] + "," + padding.top;
   return d;
  })
}).on("mouseout", function(){  
   mousex = d3.mouse(this);
   mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
   vertical.style("display", "none")});
```

1. Got rid of **HTML element div** and replaced it with a **path**. 
   As per my knowledge/experience, CSS positions mess up when the browser is resized or when the container (svg's parent)'s dimensions change. The truth is: I find this to be a simpler method and trust me, it works great if you have clip paths.
2. One important thing missing in your code was that the vertical line with a general class "remove" was being attached to every svg and there was no distinguishing between them. Here's what I am talking about:

> d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.'+selectedState)

In your case, the mousemove event resulted in showing up all vertical lines because it was being added to svgHook which in your case was just two: #main-chart-hook and #small-multiples-hook. I'm adding mouseover events for every *svg* individually with reference to it's vertical line.

3. Please don't mind but I changed a lot of code (added s, containers for paths. Take a look at the code and let me know if that works out fine for you. This is how I'm in practice when it comes to SVG coding.

Relevant code:

```
var main = state.append('g').classed('main', true);

var overlay_rect = main.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'overlay')
  .attr('width', size.w-padding.left)
  .attr('height', (size.h-padding.bottom-padding.top))
  .attr('transform', 'translate('+padding.left+', ' + padding.top+')')
  .style({'fill': 'none', 'stroke': 'none', 'pointer-events': 'all'})

var pathGroup = main.append('g').classed('paths', true);

var paths = pathGroup.selectAll("path")
```

Hope this helps and let me know if any part of the code isn't understandable :)

Comment: This works perfectly; thank you. It's also a much better solution than the one I stumbled into myself, which only has the vertical line appear when you mouseover the paths themselves (and not the background. For reference on how not to do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/SFrIKwvo8ZeUL0dM1U0r?p=preview

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Actually, I just spotted one hiccup: the vertical line doesn't appear in any of the states that have spaces in the name (District of Columbia, North Carolina, etc.). Any insight on why?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad! It's because of this: d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.'+selectedState) 
Names with spaces render as multiple classes for the svg which results in no element found. Could you take a look at how "All_States_And_Jurisdictions" is done (line no: 98)?

Comment: I'm manipulating the names so that there's only 1 class per svg. I've updated my Plunker with the same logic for the rest. Just updated line no: 113. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Aha! I see. Thanks so much again!

Comment: No problem! Good luck!